# c# variable access from many different classes

Tags: c#

What is the common way to access a variable in c#, that is used by many different functions and classes?
Should you just pass this variable to every class/function that needs it or should you better create a new instance of the class, that holds the variable and access it inside the class/function that needs to call the variable?

Comment: It depends what is your variable and how are you using that. One way is to create `Enum`. By using the `Enum` you have access that in any class you want.

Comment: Please elaborate what is the variable, because answer could differ. If it's some kind of configuration - `IOptions<>` is a good choice. If it's just some static utility value, public const class will be sufficient. If it represents common data storage, it should be DI with singleton and some mechanism of thread-safe access and so on...

Comment: There are many ways. If that value is not constant and might change like a server address or user name you should save it in a config file (txt, json, xml, etc...) and create a static class parsing / accessing the strings in that config file. If the value does not change or is not used to reference something that lives outside of your application you might want to take an approach like @EFox showed in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on on type of project and files hierarchy**

One way is to create one Base class and inherit from it to every class your using

```
class BaseController
{
    string connectionString = "..." //this is your often used variable
}

class UsersController : BaseController
{
    Connect(connectionString);

    //rest of class
}

class GroupsController : BaseController
{
    Connect(connectionString);

    //rest of class
}
```

Another way is to create class with static varibles if you can and call them without class instance

```
class MyVariables
{
    static string connectionString = "..." //this is your often used variable
}
```

And call it like this

```
Connect(MyVariables.connectionString);
```

I think The second option is better

Comment: if it works for you mark it with green chcek

Comment: The second approach is fine when defining strings which are used for application wide exceptions or messages. The first approach is much better if the base value is sufficient but might change depending on the child classes implementation and the value should be virtual so it can be overriden easily.